# get database data from mysql to vue.js in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, vue.js, vuejs2

Front end: HTML

Backend: Java servlet

I have to get data from database to vue.js to show in an HTML tag without the servlet's help. How can I get that data?

The task is a todo list. When I click on a specific button, text is stored to a database. After that, I have to display all the content that is stored in the database. This means all the data of the todo list should be displayed without the help of a select query from the servlet. How is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to run your servlet eg http://localhost:8888
2. Create API in your servlet like: POST /api/tasks/ for creation, GET /api/tasks/ to get all tasks etc.  I am not Java programmer so I am using general conventions as making API is similar in all languages. If you don't know how - use Google to find something like 'Creating API in Java'
3. Add eg. Axios to your Vue application.
4. Consume your API with axios like

   Vue.axios.get('http://localhost:8888/api/tasks').then((res)=>{
   //server response data is available in res.data
   // do whatever your want with your data
   })

Hope it helps.